# How to display multiple authors on shared posts on facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have searched for the solution of this question but I didn't get proper answer.

My website has articles that may have more than one authors. So, I added multiple Facebook Open Graph meta tags

```
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/{author_name_1}" />
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/{author_name_2}" />
```

After doing this, I shared the article on facebook, but it is showing only the name of the first author. I want to show the names of all the authors whose profile has been mentioned in the open graph meta tag. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible.

By Facebook’s definition, one article has one author, not multiple.

Comment: Thanks.
Is there any way to request this feature to Facebook?

Comment: Probably, go consult their Help section on that. But I would suspect this to have rather low chances of being implemented, it is just too special a use case.